# Android RecyclerView: Get height after set data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView with fixed height. I need to get exactly height after set data adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() and reset height of RecyclerView. How to implement that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: SetMinheight as a your fixed height and mention your height wrap content or what you want 

Comment: If you don't want to create holders for all items in one time, your Recycler have to have match_parent for widh and height. If you want change size you will need to put resycler in RelativeLayout.

Comment: And. You can read height by  using recycler.height. Just need a little wait before you call it.

Comment: My RecyclerView is nested view, it inside an other RecyclerView. so I want to height of it is fixed. If height is wrap content, data load all, not lazy load. So I want to update height after set data.